# Physical analogies of a math concepts

Tags: soft-question, intuition, education

In [a post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5892/what-is-convolution-intuitively/5916#5916) Terence Tao explained a very nice way to think about convolution and noted that "one should try to use physical intuition to model mathematical concepts whenever one can". I found this very interesting and wondered if math.stackexchange is aware of some other neat examples [Edit attempting to make the question less ambiguous] that perhaps aren't as well known as they should be.

This is a subjective question, but I consider it relevant to this site since [Edit taking note of GPerez's remark] *for certain concepts* one rarely finds these kind of things in a textbook.

Comment: You can't have checked too many textbooks.

Comment: For some things, for example the derivative, intuitive explanations are ubiquitous. However there is also the other extreme. Consider for example the determinant of a matrix. The first place I saw a nice explanation of it was [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7584/what-are-the-most-misleading-alternate-definitions-in-taught-mathematics/7952#7952).

Comment: Ok, then which are these certain ones?

Comment: I intentionally did not give a list. The point was to allow any example someone bothers to write down. A question posed this way (linked above) was approved in MO and despite being rather ambiguous, by now the question has collected many interesting answers. It's regrettable if math.stackoverflow is very strict about the way it allows information to be shared, since, what else is the point of this site?